# How do you execute a MongoDB query stored as string in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm kind of new to the MongoDB Java driver and I was wondering how you could execute a query stored as a string. Is this the best way to execute them, or what would be a better approach?

I've stumbled across the piece of the below on another stackoverflow thread, but haven't been able to get anything useful out of it. The output does not contain the result of the query at all.

The code I'm running right now:

```java
    @Test
    public void testExecuteStoredQueries() {
        String code = "db.getCollection('users').find({})";
        final BasicDBObject command = new BasicDBObject();
        String formattedCode = String.format("function() { return %s ; }", code);
        System.out.println("Formatted code:");
        System.out.println(formattedCode);
        command.put("eval", formattedCode);
        Document result = DbEngine.getInstance().getDatabase().runCommand(command);
        System.out.println(result.toJson());
    }
```

Summarized output:

```
{
    "retval": {
        "_mongo": "....",
        "_db": "...",
        "_collection": "...",
        "_ns": "cezy.users",
        "_query": {},
        "_fields": null,
        "_limit": 0,
        "_skip": 0,
        "_batchSize": 0,
        "_options": 0,
        "_cursor": null,
        "_numReturned": 0,
        "_special": false
    },
    "ok": 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use morphia when i have to deal with objects. As when you retrieve the data from MongoDb, for the long values you get extended Json instead of Json Response. Parsing Extended Json could be a trouble and might break the code. As Gson doesn't support the conversion from Extended Json to Json.

```
private void createDatastore(boolean createIndexes) {
Morphia morphia = new Morphia();
morphia.map(classname.class);

datastore = morphia.createDatastore(mongoClient, databaseName);
    if (createIndexes) {
        datastore.ensureIndexes();
    }
}

@Override
public Datastore getDatastore() {
    return this.datastore;
}

@Test
public void testExecuteStoredQueries() {
    String code = "db.getCollection('users').find({})";
     String formattedCode = String.format("function() { return %s ; }", code);
    final BasicDBObject basicObject = new BasicDBObject(new BasicDBObject("$in", formattedCode)); 
   Query<ClassName> query = getDatastore().createQuery(<Classname>.class).filter("_eval", basicObject);
   List<Classname> List = query.asList();
   //if you want to access each object and perform some task
   List.forEach((cursor) -> {
        //perform your task
    });

}
```

Comment: I can't see why the code you shared would make any difference.

Comment: This piece ```new BasicDBObject(new BasicDBObject("$in", formattedCode));``` does not make any sense

Comment: it would avoid the parser conversion from object to json to object

Answer (score 0):

Removing the function creation and adding ".toArray()" pretty much solved the problem.

```java
    @Test
    public void testExecuteStoredQueries() {
        String code = "db.users.find({}).toArray();";
        final BasicDBObject command = new BasicDBObject();
        command.put("eval", code);
        Document result = DbEngine.getInstance().getDatabase().runCommand(command);
        System.out.println(result.toJson());
        assertNotNull(result.get("retval"));
    }
```

The array is in the "retval" field of the response.